can k8s redeploy the pod when container CrashLoopBackOff error contine?
Typically, we use a container liveness prober to monitor container within a pod.
If the prober returns a failure, kubectl restarts the container not the pod.
If the container continues to have problems, it will enter the CrashLoopBackOff state.
Even in this state, the container continues to retry, but the Pod is normal.
If a container problems occurs, can I terminate the Pod itself and force it to be redistributed to another node?
The goal is to give unhealthy container one more high availability opportunity to run on another node automatically before administrator intervention.
I think it would be possible by developing operator, but I'm also curious if there's already a feature like this.

Nothing in Kubernetes is capable of doing this automatically.  You'd have to write a custom controller that did it for you.
Once a Pod is scheduled, it always stays on the Node it was assigned to (see for example How to move a pod from one node to another in kubernetes, short answer "you can't").  For this scenario you'd have to delete the Pod and let its owner (usually a ReplicaSet or StatefulSet) recreate it.  None of the built-in Pod controllers have this capability out-of-the-box.
A standard assumption in Kubernetes is that Nodes are identical and disposable.  The cluster autoscaler, for example, can dynamically create and delete cloud-hosted Nodes based on demand.  I have run into problems where I've needed to ask the operations team to terminate a Node because Pods schedule on it were misbehaving, but in practice I've gotten CrashLoopBackOff much more often due to normal startup-ordering constraints, misconfiguration, and code bugs.
(Imagine a Helm chart that deploys an application and its database simultaneously; the application Deployment won't successfully start until the database StatefulSet is up, which can't happen until a PersistentVolumeClaim is provisioned, and in this scenario it's normal for the application to be in CrashLoopBackOff for a minute or two.)
If you wanted to build this yourself, you'd need to watch Pods and examine the status:.  I don't believe CrashLoopBackOff is directly reported in the API.  Restarts are associated with individual containers, so you'd have to examine the containerStatuses:, looking for one with state: { terminated: }, where the finishedAt: time is more than some threshold ago.  If the Pod has at least one container meeting these criteria, delete it.
